# Как удалить windows с линукса?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

У меня был windows 7, я боялся поставить линукс, но все-таки решился, установив его параллельно с windows, тепер мне нужно удалить ОС windows, оставив при этом убунту линукс.
P.S.: скажу сразу, что виндовс не работает :D

Comment: Для этого придётся выучить линух на твёрдую пятёрку. Иначе и он  перестанет работать :D Ну а как выучите - сами ответ напишите.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Качаем последнюю версию [GParted Live](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/), делаем бэкапы важных файлов на отдельную железку, ставим "UNetbootin":

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:gezakovacs/ppa && sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install unetbootin
```

Втыкаем флэшку отформатированную в `FAT32`, через unetbootin выбираем "Образ диска" и указываем скачанный iso, жмём "Ок", дожидаемся окончания записи, перезагружаемся в Gparted Live.

[image: unetbootin window]

Дальше идёт то как диски обычно размечаю я. У тебя может быть по-другому, действуй по обстоятельствам.

Вот так изначально разбит жёсткий диск. 2 ОС: Windows и Linux.
[image: gparted-01]

Удаляем системный раздел с Windows.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так должно получиться.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правой кнопкой мыши кликаем на раздел с linux и жмём "Изменить размер"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мышкой тащим раздел влево до начала винта.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нас предупреждают, что всё может сломаться. Соглашаемся, потому что есть бэкапы и куча свободного времени.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Расширяем так же расширенный раздел.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перемещаем свап. Можно пересоздать, но тогда потеряется `UUID` раздела и придётся переписывать `/etc/fstab`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Расширяем хомяка влево.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Утак уот.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сносим диск `D:\`. Можем не сносить, но раз пошла такая пьянка...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как-то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Расширяем хомяка вправо на освободившееся место.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно получиться так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А теперь применяем всё то, что пронажимали через "Apply" в правом верхнем углу. Нас предупредят, что теперь изменения точно-точно применятся и поменять ничего уже будет нельзя.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если всё пройдёт гладко - будет вот такое окно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь жмём "Управление флагами" на линуксовом корневом разделе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И присваиваем ему метку `boot`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Final cut.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Лучше запастись ещё одним livecd с графикой, чтобы можно было погуглить как всё исправить, если что-то пойдёт не так и компьютер превратится в тыкву. ИМХО, [xubuntu 16.04](http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu-releases/xenial/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso) - один из наиболее оптимальных вариантов.

Comment: Не могли бы вы дать более развернутый ответ, описывающий предлагаемое решение задачи описанной в вопросе? В текущем варианте ответ не является полным. Очевидно что установкой редактора разделов задача не решается. Вероятно, вы подразумевали что с помощью этого редактора можно удалить ОС Windows. Ваш ответ будет полным если вы опишите этот процесс пошагово, включая инструкции как настроить загрузчик OS и убрать Windows из меню.

Comment: Нивапрос. Ушёл делать скрины.

Comment: @Uranus, готово.

Comment: Кто-то минус поставил. Хе-хе. Наверняка по инструкции вместе с виндовсом удалил и линух.

Comment: Ну прямо кандидатская диссертация))))) Замечательно! Спасибо!

Comment: @Trulimon, да, я помню, что много времени усадил на скрины. Ох, 16й год! Тваюмать, как быстро время-то летит!!!