# Как увеличить размер раздела ubuntu без потери данных?

Tags: ubuntu, gparted

У меня вот такие разделы на диске. И есть неразмеченные 80 gb.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли увеличить свободное место на корневом разделе и папке home не испортив данные которые там присутствуют?

Comment: да //9876543210

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587171/191416 - суть та же.