# Как перераспределить свободное место на диске между ubuntu и windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ос, ssd

Нужна помощь в таком вопросе:
У меня стоят параллельно ubuntu и вин10( сама операционка на отдельном томе C, а остальное пространство делит убунту и вин).
Есть ли способ отщепить свободное пространство во владении винды, переформатировать его и отдать линуксу? Если да, то может поможете инструкцией?
Прочитал, что могут быть проблемы, если выделяемое место слева от расположения ubuntu, кажется, у меня так и есть.
Прикладываю скриншоты из вин и линукса
Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уменьшить виндовый раздел и переместить линуксовый раздел влево. Никаких проблем быть не должно, линуксы не такие капризные как винда и обычно нормально переживают перемещение. Только для перемещения придётся загружаться с LiveCD/LiveUSB или искать специальную программу для винды, потому что сама винда перемещать разделы не умеет

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что мне нужно:
1) Уменьшить вин раздел, у меня образуется не распределенное место
2) Создаю загрузочный LiveUSB с записанной на него убунту
3) Загружаюсь с этого накопителя
4) Устанавливаю на эту убунту gparted
5) А вот дальше не совсем понимаю. В gparted я смогу перезаписать ubuntu влево? Такая функция в ней предусмотренна?

Comment: «В gparted я смогу перезаписать ubuntu влево?» — да. Только имейте в виду, что перемещение это операция долгая (хотя на NVMe возможно пройдёт быстро) и прерывать её ни в коем случае нельзя, иначе вы получите разрубленную на две части файловую систему

Comment: Окей, спасибо. Сейчас попробую

Comment: Вот это вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587171/191416 , только без кнопки "удалить", естественно.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо, кажется, я справился. @don Rumata образ с gparted почему то не сработал, пришлось через живую ставить, но инструкция всё равно очень полезная

Comment: @andreymal запускаться перестанет. восстановить загрузчики придётся

Comment: @eri если я правильно понимаю, GRUB ищет раздел с конфигами по порядковому номеру (в моём `grubx64.efi` есть строка `(,gpt2)/boot/grub` например), а так как порядок разделов не менялся, то и сломаться ничего не должно, не?

Comment: Двигал несколько раз. Ломалось. MBR загрузчик точно ломается. EFI не должен, потому как на отдельном разделе, но подстраховаться стоит.

Comment: @eri если я правильно понимаю описания в интернете, stage1.5 обычно расположен в первом мегабайте диска и ищет stage2 тоже по порядковому номеру раздела, поэтому он ломаться тоже не должен (впрочем, на практике я не проверял)