Как увеличить место для Linux за счет раздела, на котором установлена Windows?
Я на сижу на ОС Linux Mint 3 месяца, когда я ставил ее рядом с Windows 11 (c которой и пришел) я в установщике выделял место по обучению в ролике на youtube. Я вот хочу понять как правильно выделяется место для Linux Mint т.е по чего и как правильно это делать.
Я хочу это понять что бы потом оставшиеся место, которое у меня для Windows 11 передать для Linux Mint.

Уменьшить раздел с виндой, увеличить раздел с линуксом. Конкретика зависит от текущей конкретной ситуации на вашем конкретном диске

@andreymal а что мне именно увеличить какой раздел, по корень / под home под что?

А, так вы ещё и несколько разделов зачем-то создали? Ну, вам виднее, что именно вы хотите увеличить

@andreymal а разве не правильно делать разбивку / - корень, основной раздел для файловой системы;
/boot - файлы загрузчика;
/home - раздел для файлов пользователя;
swap - раздел подкачки, для выгрузки страниц из оперативной памяти, если она будет переполнена.
Скорее всего что-то путаю.

Правильность или неправильность зависит от стоящих перед системой целей, поэтому начинать всё нужно с вопроса — а зачем? Зачем отделять /home от корня? Зачем отделять /boot если загрузчик может прочитать корень напрямую? Зачем делать раздел подкачки, если можно сделать файл подкачки? Конечно, у всех этих «зачем» бывают рациональные ответы, но применимы ли они в вашем конкретном случае — вопрос открытый

@andreymal когда я устанавливал Linux Mint по инструкции по YT я делал разбивку диска по этой инструкции. А вот на вопрос зачем ? Разве не для этого: Разбивка диска для Linux на разделы обеспечивает изоляцию данных, удобство при переустановке, управление загрузчиком, повышение производительности и безопасность.

@andreymal Когда я устанавливал Linux Mint я выделил для него 30 думал не буду использовать эту систему. А сейчас я хочу ее использовать, но мне не хватает памяти на диске вот поэтому и хочу добавить на диск место с другого тома диска.

«изоляцию данных» — оно всё на одном никак не изолированном диске, так что чушь какая-то; «удобство при переустановке» — лишь отчасти применимо к разделу /home, в остальном тоже чушь; «управление загрузчиком» — а при чём тут разделы, тоже чушь какая-то; «повышение производительности» — каким образом? тоже чушь какая-то; «безопасность» — разве что если делать зашифрованные разделы и расшифровывать вручную паролем, а если нет, то похоже тоже чушь. Подозреваю, вы просто нахватались лозунгов из какой-то рандомной статейки без внятного понимания того, чем они обоснованы (и обоснованы ли вообще)

Из всего перечисленного внимания заслуживает только «удобство при переустановке», так что тут остановлюсь поподробнее — наличие отдельного раздела /home позволяет выполнить форматирование корневого раздела и переустановку линукса без затрагивания /home, что может быть удобно, особенно при частых переустановках. Однако, во-первых, а с чего бы вдруг делать частые переустановки, а во-вторых, даже если приспичит переустанавливать когда корень и /home на одном разделе — можно просто удалить все каталоги кроме /home и установить новый линукс без форматирования. [...]

[...] Поэтому рациональность отдельного раздела /home сводится скорее к размеру накопителя: если у вас какой-нибудь терабайтник или больше, можно сделать, например, корень под 100 или 200 гигов и всё остальное под /home, а если какой-нибудь полудохлый SSD на 60 гигабайт, то два малюсеньких раздела доставят кучу головной боли из-за нехватки места на них и будет проще сделать один раздел на весь диск

Возвращаясь к изначальному вопросу — раз уж вы наплодили много разделов, то тут нужно смотреть ваш конкретный случай, в каком порядке эти разделы расположены, какие размеры имеют, хватает или не хватает ли на них места, и уже потом придумывать варианты, что со всем этим можно сделать

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587171/191416 вот так, только без кнопки "удалить раздел".

@donRumata тут инструкция как передать память линукс (тупо написал)? Только в моем случае мне не нужно удалить Windows ?

@andreymal А если мне сейчас переустановить Linux Mint без разделение на разделы?

Ну. У меня там скрины про то как безопасно двигать разделы. Тебе же это надо? Ну вот. Смотри как там, но не нажимай кнопку "удалить раздел".

@donRumata а мне устанавливать UNetbootin?  Мне же вроде не надо ничего ставить, только место увеличить

@donRumata Как в линукс перекинуть файлы с системы на флешку??

Тыкаешь флэшку, она монтируется, перекидываешь. Схема работает минимум 16 лет. Если не работает - ну значит ты чё-то сломал.

Ты ставишь UNetbootin, чтобы сделать загрузочную флэшку. И с неё уже двигать разделы. Не из живой системы, а из линукса, который грузится с флэшки.

@donRumata А т.е потом уже ставлю этот линукс, который у меня в образе iso. ПОНЯЛ

Нет. Gparted Live - не ставится. Он загружается в оперативу.
